# How to configure Fuelphp?

Tags: fuelphp

I am learning Fuel php. I don't know how to configure Fuelphp. I downloaded it from Fuelphp.com. And I refer lot's of tutorial but still I am confuse about it. I copied index.php and .htaccess file from public folder and change path of `APPPATH`, `PKGPATH`, `COREPATH`

But I got warning :Warning: require(bootstrap.php)

Please help me......

Comment: Please show the *full* text of any error messages if you expect to have any chance of assistance...

Comment: @DaveRandom I got Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\FuelPhp\fuel\app\fuel\core\lasses\bootstrap.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\FuelPhp\fuel\app\bootstrap.php on line 4 

And I wrote in line no 4 of bootstrap.php: "require __DIR__.'\fuel\core\lasses\bootstrap.php';"

Comment: please ensure that `C:\wamp\www\FuelPhp\fuel\app\fuel\core\lasses\bootstrap.php` actually exists - I suspect that `lasses` should read `classes` - check that the directory is named correctly and that the `require` call points to a valid location.

Answer (score 1):

Your first mistake seems to have been editing the constants. You don't need to do that unless you are customizing the folder structure and if you are brand new to using the framework that's probably not a good idea.

```
C:\wamp\www\FuelPhp\fuel\app\fuel\core\lasses\bootstrap.php
```

Let's disect this:

```
C:\wamp\www\FuelPhp\
```

This is the root of your app. Inside here you should see "core" and "app". Instead you have:

```
C:\wamp\www\FuelPhp\fuel\app\fuel\core\
```

You have replicated the fuel folder and put core inside it? Was this intentional?

I'd start with a clean copy. Do nothing to it at all, just load up

```
http://localhost/FuelPhp/public
```

See what happens. You'll probably see the welcome page.

Comment: Thx but my question is: If I click on root directory in localhost, then my welcome controller should be load. That's why I copied index and htaccess file from public folder to root directory

Comment: Moving the .htaccess does not reconfigure Apache's Document Root for you. Set a Virtual Host to point to where the public folder is located.

Comment: Hi Phil, how would you setup a virutal host to hide the public folder in Windows?

Comment: Sorry Chris but other than setting up my elderly mothers printer I have not used a Windows computer since 2001.

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck the APPPATH, PKGPATH, COREPATH settings, probably the are wrong.

Comment: Can you give me any idea here is my cogiguration
define('APPPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'fuel/app/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);     
define('PKGPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'fuel/packages/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);     
  
define('COREPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'fuel/core/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);




This configuration is in my index.php which is located in root directory....
Please...